# Can I test for the end of the content of a text/plain file with Selenium or javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, automated-tests

I have a page that results in a text/plain file being displayed in the browser that looks like this:

```
...
Admin   Site    Administration  2010-04-21 22:26:34 admin_user@abcdef.com
Test Site   Bob Smith   2010-04-21 22:27:09 bsmith@yahoo.com
Admin   Site    Administration  2010-04-21 22:29:26 admin_user@abcdef.com
```

I am trying to write a Selenium test against this that verifies the last line of the file has "admin_user@abcdef.com" at the end. How would you do this? I can't depend on the date/time as this is a login report that is constantly getting updated - all I want is to ensure that the last line ends with that email address. And I can't figure out how to do it using Selenium expressions, DOM, or XPath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found a way that works, in Firefox at least:

```
assertText('xpath=//pre', 'regex:.*admin_user@abcdef.com$')
```

Firefox appears to create a  element in the DOM, and you can go from there. I'd be interested to see if there's any better way (especially something more cross-browser).